# Gulp: conditional execution based on output of pipeline?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, node-streams

I want to build a gulp task which exec's an external build tool (mvn) **just once** if and only if one or more files in the *src* directory are newer than any file in the *target* directory.   (In my case, checking against the date of one specific file in the target directory will do just fine.)

I've tried to combine plugins like **gulp-newer**, and **gulp-exec** which seems close to what I want, but it runs the external command too many times (once per source file), when I use them like this:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var newer = require('gulp-newer');
var exec = require('gulp-exec');

var paths = {
    src: ["pom.xml", "src/**/*", "resources/**/*", "test/**/*"],
    target: "target/antlr4-typescript-4.6-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar"
}

gulp.task('maven', function() {
    return gulp.src( paths.src)
        .pipe(newer( paths.target ))
        .pipe(exec('echo mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true'))
        .pipe(exec.reporter())
        ;
})
```

I understand why it's working this way, but how do I bridge the gap between multiple source files and invoking an external tool just once?

The docs on `gulp-exec` say:

> Note: If you just want to run a command, just run the command, don't use this plugin.

...but I don't know how to use child_process.exec if any output is generated from my `gulp.src | newer` pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about it this seems to call for a simple object-stream filter, which I've written and named [`gulp-first`](https://github.com/BurtHarris/gulp-first).   Here's what it's application looks like:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var newer = require('gulp-newer');
var first = require('gulp-first');
var exec = require('gulp-exec');

var paths = {
    src: ["pom.xml", "src/**/*", "resources/**/*", "test/**/*"],
    target: "target/antlr4-typescript-4.6-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar"
}

gulp.task('maven', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.src, { read: false })
        .pipe(newer(paths.target))
        .pipe(first())
        .pipe(exec('mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true'))
        .pipe(exec.reporter())
        ;
})
```

The gulp-exec never executes if the target is up-to-date, but executes at most once if needed.

Feedback on this solution welcome.